# Is there a preferred way to move through the 'Sector Map'?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When selecting Jump->Next Sector, you see the sector map.

This map consist of red, green, purple icons (civilian, hostile, nebula)

[image]

what's the meaning of it all?

what does nebula contains?

what is a considered a good practice to select a nebula?

Is there a good path? better path?

Comment: Found a very good reference , more can be read here - http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Sectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, hostile sectors will have more combat encounters, while civilian and nebulae tend to have more story-driven encounters. Many events in nebulae have outcomes which depend on having a specific system on a specific level, so they favor generalism over specialization. Civilian sectors have the most shopping opportunities, so when you have a lot of scrap to spend, you might want to fly through a civilian sector. But these differences are not that large.

But it's not just the color which is relevant. A far more interesting information is who controls a given sector, because this determines which events and enemies you will encounter. Depending on where you place your focus while upgrading your ship, it might be more or less fit for certain enemies and events you will encounter. Also, when you want to unlock new ship designs: Many of them can only be unlocked through events which only occur in sectors controlled by specific races.

Comment: This is great Philip!! I never new this stuff and it'll help me/others to master this great game, 10x!!